# React setState Date returns null - calculating date/time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, time

I would like to calculate time difference in React. Later on I would like to post the current date in a database and compare it to the current time, basically a time tracker. But when setting state it always returns 0 and I don't understand why/what other options do I have?

```
const TimeComp = (props) => {
  const [Timer, setTimer] = useState(0)
  const [StartTime, setStartTime] = useState(0)

  const handleStart = () => {  
    setStartTime(new Date().getTime())
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(StartTime)
      setTimer(new Date().getTime() - StartTime)
    }, 1000)
    }
  
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleStart}>Start</button>
          <h2> {Timer} </h2>
      </div>
            )
}
```

console.log(StartTime) returns 0 every time, even with the interval.
I would like it to return the unix timestamp ~ 1616440460597

setTimer(new Date().getTime() however successfully returns the unix timestamp

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

it works when instead of using state i use

```
const handleStart = () => {  
    let today = new Date().getTime()
    setInterval(() => {
      console.log(StartTime)
      setTimer(new Date().getTime() - today)
    }, 1000)
    }
```